# BOOST scoped_lock replacement in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I am facing a situation where I have to replace a BOOST scoped_lock with an equivalent in C++11. Under visual studio 2013. Since c++11 does not supprt scoped_lock, I am not sure what the replacement code for the following would be. Should I go for lock_guard or try_lock ?

```
boost::mutex::scoped_lock objectLock(ObjectVectorMutex, boost::try_to_lock);
if (objectLock) {
  // ...
}
```

And down in the code I have the following 'wait' statement

```
if (ObjectsCollection.empty()) {
  // This is where we wait til something is filled
  MotionThreadCondition.wait(objectLock);
  ElapsedTime = 0;          
}
```

Any guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`std::unique_lock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock) instead of `scoped_lock`:

```
std::unique_lock objectLock(ObjectVectorMutex, std::try_to_lock);
```

And `MotionThreadCondition` would be a [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), used the same way. However, instead of `if(condition)` you should do `while(condition)` to handle [spurious wakeups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_wakeup) correctly.

Comment: actually it is not only a question of handling spurious wakeups, but plain concurrency correctness. Even without spurious it is necessary to loop because in cases of 3-threaded programs some other actor could lock the mutex faster and modify the condition.

Comment: @v.oddou I don't follow. We actually don't know how he is using the `condition_varaible`, it might not be with a condition at all (which is unsafe because of spurious wakeups); in which case he would want `if(collection.empty()){ while(otherCondition) var.wait(lock); }`

Comment: @v.oddou - Thanks for the tip on condition_variable. I am sticking with if(collection.empty()) way!